# Why is Youtube draining the battery and what could we do?

Tags: battery-life, youtube, google-apps

A friend of mine just asked me a nice question:

His (stock) Samsung Galaxy S4's Youtube is draining his battery.
He said, that he hasn't been in the app today, and this morning he had the phone booting up.

Now, Youtube drained 51% of his battery.

I know, there are many possibilities, to "solve" this, like:

- Rebooting the Phone to get rid of the wakelock
- Terminating the Youtube-app via the Settings -> Apps menue
- Clearing Cache/Deleting Data
- Uninstalling Updates and deactivating the app

But **besides** these workarounds:

Is there any fix for this issue?

What could one do, if he'd have to terminate the app everytimes he boots up his phone?

Is there even something to do?

**/NOTE**

We try to achieve a better information about what exactly in the YT-app causes the battery drain using Better Battery Stats.
Stats will follow.

Comment: Is his firmware up-to-date?

Answer (score 2):

Try to install [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?hl=es&id=com.oasisfeng.greenify).

> It helps you identify and put the misbehaving apps into hibernation
>   when you are not using them, to stop them from lagging your device and
>   leeching the battery

Comment: It is a unrooted phone. And: Greenify is an app-solution. It's great, correct. But isn't there anything else that can be done but installing a third party app?

Comment: Greenefy works on unrooted devices. Try to block the process when you are not using it. I found this post, can help you(Spanish)
http://www.grupoandroid.com/topic/52737-optimizar-rendimiento-en-ics-sin-ser-root/

Answer (score 0):

Greenify too, add YT to the app-to-close list when hibernate. You can do it another way. Run battery Doctor and locate YouTube in the list of running apps. Close YouTube, then turn off wifi and screen.

Answer (score 0):

Get LeanDroid, thats the best one ive found (ive tried greenify, sounds great but isnt quite as good) but greenify is more straight forward. LeanDroid, takes more configuring. I am using a S6, my battery life is nearly 3x

Answer (score 0):

Relaunching the YouTube app while offline fixed it for me, try closing and opening it while keeping the WiFi off

Answer (score -1):

Greenify is a good application but the issue is that YouTube drain a lot of battery when you are watching videos and doing anything. I have seen in Greenify that background YouTube not drain battery; if you open it then it start draining battery battery.

So I think disable YouTube app and gets alternative that don't drain battery. for that I suggest [NewPipe](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.schabi.newpipe).

Comment: Very much in agreement about newpipe from a personal perspective, but the user has asked about a system app. Installing another isn't going to fix the youtube issue